# How to deal with ffmpeg streaming glitches

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm currently recording a live audio stream with ffmpeg and I'm wondering how ffmpeg deals with glitches in the broadcast.

To illustrate an example, ffmpeg is recording a live stream and for some reason on the broadcasting end there is a glitch for say 2 seconds, how is this interpreted by ffmpeg?

Does ffmpeg simply wait for new data to come in? If this is the case then there will be 2 seconds missing in my recording which means that if this happens a few times that wall time is out of sync with the recording.

Or, does ffmpeg cater to the fact that no audio was coming through for those 2 seconds and outputs 2 seconds of silence?

What is the best way to record a live stream with ffmpeg and cater for glitches that might occur on the broadcaster end?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/474004/mjpeg-recording-with-ffmpeg-preserving-time-information

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily, ffmpeg won't inject silence, but for capturing an audio-only stream, you can use the aresample filter to inject silence if there are gaps in the input i.e. `-af aresample=async=1`